# ユーザー登録を後から行う時のエラーメッセージにHTMLが表示されている

Tags: バグ, 完了

再現方法

1. ユーザー登録せずに投稿
2. ヘッダに表示されている[登録を完了する]をクリック
3. 投稿時に入力したものとは異なるメールアドレスと任意のパスワードを入力して送信
4. 下のようにエラーが表示されるが、HTMLがそのまま表示されている

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この時点のURLは `https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/signup-unregistered/submit` です。

ちなみにTransifex上はこのフレーズです： https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40289472?key=beab14c9fad2f6a932402ce2678eda48

---

Reproducing the bug:

1. Post without registering
2. Click on "Complete Registration" in the header
3. Put in a different e-mail/password than when you posted
4. The below error comes out and raw HTML is visible

The URL at the time of the error is `https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/signup-unregistered/submit`

This is the phrase in Transifex: https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40289472?key=beab14c9fad2f6a932402ce2678eda48

Comment: エンコーディングは２回行っているらしいです。英語以外のサイトのみに発生しています。問題箇所はわかっていますが、英語版に影響がないかを確認した上で今週に治す予定です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

現在、 [「ゲストとして投稿」機能を無効にして欲しい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3751/3054) の要望が受け入れられ、ユーザーが「登録せずに投稿」ということは無くなりました。

（おそらく、それ以前に修正されていたことと思います。今後も新規ユーザーに表示されるUIに注意を払う必要は有りそうです）