# 「ゲストとして投稿」機能を無効にして欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, アカウント

スタック・オーバーフローにおいてはアカウント登録をせずに「ゲストとして投稿」を行うことができ、この仕組み自体は質問を気軽に行うためのものだろうと考えています。

しかし、このゲスト投稿はブラウザの Cookie のみでログイン情報を識別しているため、恐らく本人も意図しない2つ目のアカウントを作成してしまうトラブルが度々発生しています。

より具体的には、質問者本人の投稿であれば (ゲスト投稿であっても) 後から編集を行うことができるはずですが、二つ目のアカウントに分かれてしまうことで質問が編集できずに「回答欄に追加情報を投稿」や「本人なのに編集提案」のようなイレギュラーがアクションが発生し、コミュニティユーザーも内容の確認やサイトの仕組みを教える手間がかかっています。

---

「ゲストとして投稿」は各サイトごとの方針によって有効・無効を選択しているようなので、可能であれば日本語版においては無効にして欲しいです。

**関連の討議:**

[質問者本人によるものかを確認出来ない情報の追記、削除を伴う編集提案を承認するべきか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3373/3060)

---

### 追記:

コメントを使って「問い合わせフォームを案内すればいい」とありますが、今回の要望は「コミュニティユーザーがコメントで案内する負担を減らしたい」のがそもそもの目的であり、コメントでの案内は既に実施しています。 (常態的に発生しているからこその要望です)

#### 「ゲスト投稿」が抱える現状の問題点

##### 投稿者視点

他の関連する要望や質問を行っても、重複アカウントが発生するのは「Cookieで管理しているから」の一点張りですが、投稿画面で十分な説明がされていません。

「異なる Cookie」も、例えば "自宅" と "職場または学校" など異なる環境からであれば分からなくもないですが、実際に発生しているケースでは (モデレータツールで確認する限り) 同一のネットワークから、極端な場合は投稿から30分も経たずに別アカウントが作成されています。

わざわざ別のブラウザを使いまわすことも考えづらく、詳しく聞き取りをしたわけではありませんが「プライベートブラウジング」などを使っているケースも考えられます。

ブラウザの Cookie だけでユーザーをユニークに識別しようとすることが今の時代にそぐわないと思います。

##### コミュニティ視点

繰り返しになりますが、コミュニティとしては「コメント欄でアカウントのマージ方法を知らせる」というアクションは既に実施しています。

"稀に発生する" レベルなら仕方ありませんが、英語質問と同様に数日おきでコンスタントに発生しておりコミュニティへの負担が積み重なっています。

他の (却下または放置された) 要望も同様に、システムで解決すべき問題をコミュニティの人力で対処させようとするのは、ボランティアの意味をはき違えていると思います。
自分たちが利用するサイトだから止む無く対処していますが、あくまで「質問や回答を投稿するため」に訪れているのであり、**サイトの穴を埋め続けるのが目的ではありません。**

- [英語質問のブロック](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2523)
- [翻訳済みテキストが英語に戻ってしまう](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3002)
- [未翻訳の文字列が使用されている箇所を確認できる機能が欲しい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3098)

Comment: この提案に賛成です。質問者が2つ目のアカウントを作成してしまったときアカウントのマージが行われず、質問だけが残るケースもしばしば見られ、問題だと思います。

Answer (score 6):

**更新：** コミュニティ管理チームのメンバーとさらに話し合い、無効にするかどうかを再検討した結果、スタック・オーバーフローにおける「ゲストとして投稿」機能を無効にしました。 今回のケースは通常とは異なりますが、ある一定の不快感を引き起こしていることがわかり、無効にすることによってすぐに問題が引き起こされてしまうというマイナス要素もないように思われます。

---

この機能は、投稿に含めてくださった通り、新規ユーザーがより簡単に質問を投稿しやすくするために存在します。そのため、通常ではサイトで大量のスパムが発生している場合や、その結果として投稿内容の品質が低下している場合にのみ無効にしています。今回の主な理由はアカウントの重複であるように読み取れるので、このリクエストをステータスを[却下](/questions/tagged/%e5%8d%b4%e4%b8%8b)といたします。

別の方法として、重複アカウントユーザーに[「お問い合わせ」フォーム](/contact) を紹介すると、そこからアカウントのマージが可能です。また、メールアドレスから同一人物であることが明らかな場合には、モデレーターから [CM チームへエスカレーション](/help/mod-cm-contact)するとアカウントがマージされます。

Comment: 現状、「新規ユーザーがより簡単に質問を投稿しやすくする」機能は果せていません。
新規ユーザーに混乱の種をバラ撒いているだけです。
結果として「投稿内容の品質が低下している」のは明らかです。
「重複アカウントユーザーに『お問い合わせ』フォーム を紹介する」などといった事は、既にやっています。
しかし、このような事態は他のサイトでは起こり得ず、新規ユーザーが事態を理解し、正しく対応するのは困難です。

Comment: この機能の結果として、質問者がサイトを離れて質問が途中放棄され、回答者のモチベーションも下げています。
このメタ質問に賛成票しか入っていないことの意味を考えて下さい。

Comment: @JNat  こんにちは！あなたのサポートが必要です。Would you be available to take a look at this issue sometime this month, to dig up some numbers..  I am not quite sure what could be quantifiable here, but if the confusion is actually greater than the benefit of welcoming/easy access for new users here at SOja, then we will want to improve it.

Comment: I will add an item to our backlog to get some data on this, @aki  — hopefully someone can look into it next week ^_^

Comment: @JNat It's been a month, any info?

Comment: Heh why some in English?

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Communication here is mostly in Japanese but occasionally in English.. もちろんですが、日本語が奨励されています❤️