# ヘルプセンターのユーザー登録に関する説明を見直したい

Tags: 討議, ヘルプ

スタック・オーバーフローにおいて質問 (または回答) の投稿を行うには「ユーザー登録必須」とするよう、[コミュニティでの話し合いで設定の変更を行いました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3751) が、ヘルプセンターを開くと以下の通り古い説明が残ったままになっているため、記述の見直しをしたいです。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help

> #### ユーザー登録やログインは必要ですか？
>
> 一切必要ありません。 質問も回答も匿名で投稿することができます。
> ユーザー登録して初めてアクセスできる機能も一部あります。ユーザー登録したくなったら、FacebookやGoogleなどのOpenID機能を使ってとても簡単にすませることができます。

手っ取り早くは該当部分の削除だけでもよさそうですが、代わりに「ユーザー登録必須」の説明を載せた方が良い等、意見があれば聞かせてください。

---

補足:

ヘルプセンターには [アカウントを作成するのはなぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/why-register) のページもあるのですが、対象が Stack Exchange 全般とも読めるのと、ゲスト投稿が無効な [英語版でもそのままの文章](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-register) なので、こちらはひとまずそのままで良いかなと個人的に思っています。

Answer (score 2):

該当部分の削除だけではもったいないと感じたので、説明文を考えてみました。

ユーザー登録やログインは必要ですか？
閲覧目的ならば必要ありません。 匿名でも質問や回答、コメント、投票数をすべて表示します。
質問や回答を投稿するにはログインが必要です。ユーザー登録して[信用度](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)を上げることでアクセスできる機能も一部あります。(例えば[どこでもコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)には信用度50が必要です)
ユーザー登録したくなったら、FacebookやGoogleなどのOpenID機能を使ってとても簡単にすませることができます。

※閲覧数、回答数や解決済みフラグも匿名で表示できますが冗長なので省略しています。
※信用度をあげなくてもログインで[セーブ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3926/%e3%83%98%e3%83%ab%e3%83%97%e3%82%bb%e3%83%b3%e3%82%bf%e3%83%bc%e7%bf%bb%e8%a8%b3-how-do-i-use-saves)機能が解放されると認識していますが同上です。

Answer (score 2):

該当部分を削除するだけで十分であり、「ユーザー登録必須」などの説明は必要無いと思います。

理由:

- 短くなければ読まれないので、他で伝わる内容は省略すべき（現在、英語版は省略が進んでおり、かなり短くなっています）
- 投稿にあたって登録が必要なのは多くのサイトで共通で、説明が無くとも予想される
- 「質問する」ボタンを押すとログイン／登録画面に遷移し、「質問するには、ログインする必要があります」と説明が有る
- 回答箇所には「この質問に回答するには、ログインする必要があります」と説明が有る