# ヘルプセンター翻訳：How do I use Saves?

Tags: サポート, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

この投稿は [How do I use Saves?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/saves) の翻訳案です。

（@cubickさんが[翻訳部屋](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20999/soja-translators)にて未翻訳であることに気づいてくださいました。ありがとうございます！）

---

Title: セーブを使用するには？

### 後で参照できるように質問や回答をセーブするにはどうすればよいですか?

質問または回答をセーブするには、投稿の左端、投票矢印のすぐ下にある [セーブ] アイコンをクリックします。次のようになります：

[image: Save icon]

### セーブを整理するにはどうすればよいですか?

[セーブ] ページから、リストに項目を追加したり、非公開のメモを追加/削除したりできます。どちらの場合も、セーブした投稿の右端の縦三点リーダー「︙」をクリックして小さなメニューを開きます。すると次の操作が可能になります：

- **セーブを解除**（リストから投稿を削除します）
- **移動**（投稿を別のリストに移動します）
- **非公開メモの追加**（アカウント所有者のみに表示されるメモを追加します）
- **非公開メモの編集**（投稿にすでにある非公開メモを編集します）
- **非公開メモの削除**（投稿の非公開メモを削除します）

### リストを作成するにはどうすればよいですか？

「マイリスト」の右側にある「＋」アイコンをクリックすると、新しいリストを作成できます。 [すべてのセーブ] リストと [あとで読む] リストにある、青い [新しいリストを作成する] ボタン (右上隅) をクリックして、新しいリストを作成することもできます。

[image: ユーザープロフィールの [セーブ] タブのスクリーンショット。デフォルトで [すべての保存] ページが表示されています。ページの左側にある [マイリスト] と右上の [新しいリストを作成する] ボタンは丸で囲まれています。]

### セーブしたものを検索するにはどうすればよいですか？

`in:saves` 検索演算子を使用して、セーブした投稿を [検索](/help/searching) することができます。

### 他の誰かが私のセーブリストやメモを閲覧することができますか？

いいえ、閲覧できるのはあなただけです！

---

この機能の詳細については Meta Stack Exchange の投稿（英語）をご参照ください： [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/335251)

Answer (score 1):

反映が完了しました♪

[image]