# 「ゲストとして投稿」機能を利用した際に作成されたアカウントの扱いは？

Tags: サポート, アカウント

一年ほど前までスタック・オーバーフローには、「ゲストとして投稿」という機能がありました。これはアカウントを作成する手順を伴わずに、ユーザ名とメールアドレスを入力するだけで質問ができるという機能でした。

[image: ゲストとして投稿機能のスクリーンショット。2列あるうちの左側にはログイン用のフォームが、右側にはゲストとして投稿するために必要な情報を入力するフォームがある。]

この機能は、サイトを新しく訪れたユーザからの質問投稿を促進するために導入されていましたが、現在は[コミュニティからのフィードバックを受けて廃止](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3751/32986)されています。

ここで疑問があります。「ゲストとして投稿」機能が廃止されるにあたって、「ゲストとして投稿」が行えた当時のゲストアカウントは、どのような扱いになっているのでしょうか？今からでもパスワードを設定すれば使えるケースや、完全に使えなくなっているケースなど、いくつかのパターンが考えられますが、実際にどのように扱われているのかは、どの資料でも明らかになっていないと思います。

Answer (score 3):

明確には答えられませんが、私の推測などを述べます（なお、心配する材料などが出るまでは、私からStack Exchange社に問い合わせる予定は無いです）。

#### 推測される状況

- ログイン状態が継続可能
- 投稿不可能
- 登録手続きにより登録ユーザーになれる

#### このサイトの状況

- 無効化された2022年9月13日以降、ゲストアカウントによる投稿は2件です
  （削除済を含みません。現時点で登録ユーザーになっているアカウントによるものも含みません。）

  - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/54378/yukky?tab=activity
  - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/53981/futa?tab=activity
- どちらも9月13日午前のもので、ギリギリ無効化以前であったと思われます
- ログインした状態でのアクセスに関してはそれ以降も行なわれています

#### 他のサイトの状況

「ゲストとして投稿」機能が無効化されたサイトはいくつも有ります。その中には本家Stack Overflowなど、ユーザー数が多い所も見られます。これらのサイトで問題が報告されていないので、しかるべく対処されているのだろうと推測します。

Blender Stack Exchang における無効化時の報告では、既存のアカウントに影響しないとされています。

> This will not affect any of the current users or existing accounts, nor how the site works,
>
> —— https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3022